# Angular unit test HttpClientTestingModule no request being generated?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have set up a service which I am trying to write a test for.

It uses the https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt library. I am providing the AuthHttp service, but tell the test to use Http instead

The service itself seems to be working fine, but I am struggling to write the test.

I am trying to use the HttpClientTestingModule from Angular to mock the http response and test the values, but it seems that my 'getLookups' function in the service is never getting executed?

```
getLookup(id: number): Observable<Lookup[]> {
    const _lookups: Subject<Lookup[]> = new Subject();
    const lookups: Observable<Lookup[]> = _lookups.asObservable();

       this.authHttp.get(this.config.api.baseAPI + '/api/property/' + id + '/lookup')

        .subscribe(data => {

                const lookupsRaw = data.json();
                const lookUpsParsed: Lookup[] = [];
                lookupsRaw.forEach((lup) => {
                    lookUpsParsed.push(new Lookup(lup.id, lup.label));
                });

                 console.log(lookUpsParsed);
                _lookups.next(lookUpsParsed);
            },
            err => console.log('Error!!!!'+ err),
            () => console.log('Request Complete!!')
        );
    return lookups;
}
```

This is the test that I am strying to run

```
describe('SurveyService', () => {



beforeEach(() => {


    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [HttpModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
        providers: [
            AuthHttp,
            SurveyService,
            ConfigurationService,
            {provide: AuthHttp, useExisting: Http}


        ]
    });


});

afterEach(inject([HttpTestingController], (httpMock: HttpTestingController) => {
    httpMock.verify();
}));

 it('should be created',
    inject([HttpTestingController, SurveyService], (httpMock: HttpTestingController, service: SurveyService) => {

            expect(service).toBeTruthy();

            service.getLookup(7).subscribe(lookup => {


            });
        const req = httpMock.expectOne('/api/property/7/lookup');
        req.flush({name: 'Test Data'});
        }
    ));

});
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong with that one please?

Thanks, Uwe

Comment: What error did you get? What's the `Http` of `useExisting` property? You need to provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), don't  put the unrelated code.

Answer (score 1):

try doing doing something like this:

```
it('',async(done)=>{ 
 ...
 service.getLookup(7).subscribe(lookup => {
  expect(...).tobe(...);
  done();
   });
});
```

my guess is that since your code is async, you need to wait for it to make a response. This is one way to do just that